# Javascript beginner programming quesion

Tags: javascript

This is my coding.

```js
switch(education){
    case "no highschool diploma":
        salary="25636";
        break;
    case "a high school diploma":
        salary="35256";
        break;
    case "an Associate's degree":
        salary = "41496";
        break;
    case "an Bachelor's degree":
        salary = "59124";
        break;
    case "an Master's degree":
        salary = "69732";
        break;
    case "an Professional degree":
        salary = "89960";
        break;
    case "an Doctoral degree":
        salary = "84396";
        break;
}
console.log("In 2015, a person with "+education+" earned an average of "+ salary.toLocaleString("en-US") +"/year.");
```

I wanna know why the result is

> In 2015, a person with a high school diploma earned an average of 35256/year.

Instead of

> In 2015, a person with a high school diploma earned an average of 35,256/year.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: what value does have `education`?

Answer (score 3):

Your values are strings, make them numbers:

```js
const stringVariable = "12345";
const numberVariable = 12345;

console.log(stringVariable.toLocaleString("en-US")); // Logs 12345
console.log(numberVariable.toLocaleString("en-US")); // Logs 12,345
```

Answer (score 3):

you are working with String type, you need to convert to number first.
`console.log("In 2015, a person with "+education+" earned an average of "+ Number(salary).toLocaleString("en-US") +"/year.");`

Answer (score 0):

This is because salary="35256" is passed as a string. Try changing to salary=35256 and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Different data types ( e.g. Number, String, Date ) often have their own implementation of `.toLocaleString()`

Because you call `.toLocaleString()` on a String, you are currently using the default implementation as defined in the Object data type, which isn't being overwritten.

However if you want to use the version associated with a Number. You can cast a String to a Number using `Number()` before you call `.toLocaleString()`.

If you want to learn more read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString

**demo**

```js
const education = "a high school diploma";

switch(education){
    case "no highschool diploma":
        salary="25636";
        break;
    case "a high school diploma":
        salary="35256";
        break;
    case "an Associate's degree":
        salary = "41496";
        break;
    case "an Bachelor's degree":
        salary = "59124";
        break;
    case "an Master's degree":
        salary = "69732";
        break;
    case "an Professional degree":
        salary = "89960";
        break;
    case "an Doctoral degree":
        salary = "84396";
        break;
}
console.log("In 2015, a person with "+education+" earned an average of " + Number(salary).toLocaleString("en-US") +"/year.");
```